# Map operator returning integer as output with array as input

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

This is example code from the docs. I am new to RXJS, so this might be real easy.

Can anyone explain how map operator is returning a single digit integer after operating on an array?

I checked that the return value of scan operator is an array which increases from [0], [0,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,2,3] .... and so on.

```
// RxJS v6+
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { scan, map, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Accumulate values in an array, emit random values from this array.
const scanObs = interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    scan((a, c) => [...a, c], []),
    map(r => r[Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length)]),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: `map` here maps `r` (array) into a single item in that array `r[...]`. So it takes an array (`number[]`) is input and outputs a random item (`number`).

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce

Comment: But the way map works on arrays, should it not take each element of array and perform the action and store it in array and return the array. Map usually operates on each value of array and returns the array

Answer (score 0):

Interval emits an incrementing integer every second, scan then adds that integer to an array and then the map pulls out a random element of that array and distinctUntilChanged stops it from emitting the same number twice in a row. A much more efficient way to get a random number where the highest possible number increases by one each time would be much more efficient with

```js
const { interval } = rxjs;
const { map, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;

interval(1000).pipe(
  map(i => Math.ceil(Math.random() * i)),
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

No need to store all previous values in an array.